# How can I limit the dates that can be selected in this Date Picker in Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I need to limit the dates that CAN be selected to only 2017!? any help would really be appreciated!

```
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0/build/calendar    /assets/skins/sam/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><script     type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0    /build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script> <script     type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0    /build/calendar/calendar-min.js"></script>     <script>Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function(){var qid =this.questionId;    var calid = qid +'_cal';var y =QBuilder('div');
  $(y).setStyle({clear:'both'});var d =QBuilder('div',{className:'yui-skin-    sam'},[QBuilder('div',{id:calid}),
y
  ]);var c =this.questionContainer;
  c = $(c).down('.QuestionText');
  c.appendChild(d);var cal1 =new YAHOO.widget.Calendar(calid); 
  cal1.render();var input = $('QR~'+ qid);
  $(input).setStyle({marginTop:'20px',width:'150px'});var p =$(input).up();    var x =QBuilder('div');
  $(x).setStyle({clear:'both'});
  p.insert(x,{position:'before'});
    cal1.selectEvent.subscribe(function(e,dates){var date = dates[0]    [0];if(date[1]<10)
        date[1]='0'+ date[1];if(date[2]<10)
        date[2]='0'+ date[2];
    input.value = date[1]+'-'+date[2]+'-'+date[0];})});</script>`
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var cal1 = new YAHOO.widget.Calendar("cal1","cal1Container", 
                                                         { pagedate: "1/5/2017", 
                                                           mindate: "1/5/2017", 
                                                           maxdate: "1/15/2017" } 
                                                         );
```

Comment: Sorry Joel I'm pretty new to coding... how would I include that in what I have? Also do I need to change those dates to be 12/31/17 etc??

Comment: Figured it out... that pointed me in the right direction! Thanks!!

Comment: When you need to deal with dates, see momentjs : [link](https://momentjs.com/). In the future, it will be part of Date Api in JavaScript.